# Is there a canonical question where asker doesn't know what a browser extension or userscript is, but is essentially asking how to make one?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, canonical

I just came accross this: [How to import javascript code into developer tools in browser? One time forever](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66792424/11107541)

And tried looking for something to mark is as a duplicate of.

I found this: [How do I add a simple script to my browser to always run on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69640106/11107541), which is close, but is specifically asking about Google Chrome.

I found this: [Load my custom JS for every page I visit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24768237/11107541), but it contains a lot of specific context that isn't relevant to the question I want to say is a duplicate.

I tried looking through some of the highest upvoted questions tagged [userscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/userscript)/[content-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/content-script), but couldn't find one asking something like "what is a userscript?" (Go figure).

Is there a question asking something like "How can I make a client-side JS script only for myself on my machine that can run on any sites of my choosing that I visit using a web browser?" and maybe even asking "What options are there and what are the main tradeoffs?"

Or am I asking the wrong question here? Maybe I should instead be asking (?):

- Should such a question exist at all?

  - Would it be too broad?
  - Should I be voting to close questions in a similar vein to [How to import javascript code into developer tools in browser? One time forever](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66792424/11107541) for reasons other than being duplicates?
- Should [How to import javascript code into developer tools in browser? One time forever](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66792424/11107541) be the canonical question that the other ones get considered as being marked as duplicates of?

  - It still contains some user-specific-context (hiding youtube screen cards), but it's much less than there is in [Load my custom JS for every page I visit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24768237/11107541).

Comment: I added the last vote needed to close it as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60292446/run-my-javascript-code-on-every-page-on-my-browser-similar-to-how-a-chrome-exte

Comment: I've been wanting to know how to make a userscript, but too afraid to ask ;-)

Comment: Here I want to post an answer but I really can't. It wants a yes answer but there's more to the question that needs someone with more knowledge to finish the answer.

Comment: Are questions about how to browse the web "on topic" for stackoverflow.com? I suppose user-scripts are a type of code.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I feel unsure if closing it as a duplicate of a google-chrome-specific question is the right call. The question is browser agnostic. What was your rationale for that choice?

Comment: Neither the question nor the answer(s) are Chrome-specific, despite the title. From the OP: "Is there a way to have some JavaScript code that my browser (Chrome or Firefox) would load every time I visited a new page?"

Comment: Whoops. I just saw the tags and didn't read the body carefully. I'm going to edit the tags.